# System Integrity Protection for Linux

Tags: permissions, fedora, security, root, integrity

I'm looking for a way to protect certain folders from any manipulation and write attempts (also from the root user as with macOS). I've already looked for options, but I haven't found anything useful. Any possibility such as adding the immutable attribute to a folder can easily be bypassed by the root user with `chattr -i`. And creating a separate partition that is mounted as read-only is not an option for my use case, because I only want to protect certain folders in the file system like /bin but also files like /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot protect yourself from a rogue root user. By definition it has full access to the system, including the ability to load/unload kernel modules, modify the kernel memory, etc. etc. etc.

If you're looking for a way to protect the system against yourself, I've no idea, I'm not sure it's possible.

If you want to secure the system, make sure no one but you can access root, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

While within the traditional Unix permission model (Discretionary access control, `DAC`) the `root` user is all-powerful and can't be restricted from accessing certain files you still can restrict even the `root` by using `SELinux` to implement Mandatory Access controls `MAC`. For actual implementation see a blog post by Sven Vermeulen [Restricting even root access to a folder](https://blog.siphos.be/2015/07/restricting-even-root-access-to-a-folder/).