# How to make a directory only accessible by local user not remote root user?

Tags: centos, ssh, permissions, root

I have a CentOS 7.9 machine, logging in as my normal user account and access a directory that has my forms and SSN in it. Other users in the network who has the root account can ssh to my box and access these files (Everyone can ssh to any machine on the network and become root). How can I prevent them from doing so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System Integrity Protection for Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687284/system-integrity-protection-for-linux)

Comment: You can prevent root from being able to see the content of your file(s) by encrypting them. Root users will still be able to delete and/or tamper with your files.

Comment: Note what you describe as "remote root user" actually is a "local root user" that logged in from remote. Once logged in, "root == root", so you probably want to prevent root login by others.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, `root`, or more specifically **the user which has User ID 0** can have access to any directory, you cannot restrict the access for this user.

Comment: @White Owl - I have no power on who can become root, and anyone who can become root can log into any machine on the network. So I guess I am out of luck

Comment: The security policy is really from hell then.

Answer (score 0):

You do not hide your files from the root.

You prevent non-trusted people to become a root on your machine.